# direction routes in react native not shown

Tags: react-native-maps

first i use react-native-maps to locate the expo app in toronto,and i use react-native-maps-directions to draw route between two location in toronto.MapView component works,but its child component MapViewDirections not working.no error notification.
"react-native-maps": "0.30.2",
"react-native-maps-directions": "1.8.0"
code like below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';



const LATITUDE = 43.653225;
const LONGITUDE = -79.383186;
export default function App() {

  const origin = {latitude: 43.791680, longitude: -79.312770};
  const destination = {latitude: 43.785230, longitude: -79.293420};
  const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'myapikey';

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView  provider="google"
      initialRegion={{
          latitude: LATITUDE,
          longitude: LONGITUDE,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }} 
      style={styles.map} >
      <MapViewDirections
    origin={origin}
    destination={destination}
    apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
    onError={(errorMessage) => {
      console.log('GOT AN ERROR');
    }}
  />
   </MapView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I found the solution after I check MapViewDirections's source code .MapViewDirections component has very special logic while using,this component constructed with react-native-maps,so it should be work with MapView.And secondly,its state should be shown after re-render,I use usestate to make its state rendered.I paste code here:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';
import { useState } from 'react';



const LATITUDE = 43.653225;
const LONGITUDE = -79.383186;
export default function App() {
  const [coordinates] = useState([
    {
      latitude: 43.791680, longitude: -79.312770,
    },
    {
      latitude: 43.785230, longitude: -79.293420,
    },
  ]); 

  const origin = {latitude: 43.791680, longitude: -79.312770};
  const destination = {latitude: 43.785230, longitude: -79.293420};
  const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'AIzaSyBpAexI1D_HPIrR9xz_RqAAKDNlYKmW0Q8';

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
        style={styles.maps}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: coordinates[0].latitude,
          longitude: coordinates[0].longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0622,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
        }}>
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={coordinates[0]}
          destination={coordinates[1]}
          apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY} // insert your API Key here
          strokeWidth={4}
          strokeColor="#111111"
        />
        <Marker coordinate={coordinates[0]} />
        <Marker coordinate={coordinates[1]} />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  maps: {
    width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height,
  },
})
```